# Gravity Forms Conditionally Required Field

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am using Gravity Form in a WordPress installation.  I need field {:10} to only be required if field {:5} is not blank.  I believe the code I need to use is :

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', 'gw_conditional_requirement' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation', 'gw_conditional_requirement' );
function gw_conditional_requirement( $form ) {
    $value = rgpost( 'input_5' );
    if ( $value == 'no' ) {
        return $form;
    }

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        if ( $field->id == 10 ) {
            $field->isRequired = true;
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

I put the code in using PHP Snippets, but I am not having any luck.  What am I doing wrong?